# MySQL GROUP BY without removing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use GROUP BY without it removing duplicates. My table looks like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|user|guess|score|
+----+-----+-----+
|abc |12345|5    |
|def |67890|8    |
|ghi |11121|5    |
|jkl |31415|13   |
|mno |16171|4    |
|pqr |81920|13   |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Whenever I do `SELECT user, score FROM guesses GROUP BY score`, I get this:

```
+----+-----+
|user|score|
+----+-----+
|mno |4    |
|abc |5    |
|def |8    |
|jkl |13   |
+----+-----+
```

And I want this (below) in which duplicates are alphabetized.

```
+----+-----+
|user|score|
+----+-----+
|mno |4    |
|abc |5    |
|ghi |5    |
|def |8    |
|jkl |13   |
|pqr |13   |
+----+-----+
```

I'm doing a high-score system with guesses, but it won't be fair if it removes duplicates.

Do you think it may have something to do with the way PHP parses it? I'm using phpMyAdmin, so that should show the right output...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using GROUP BY?

Comment: The example table you show does not have a column called `chars`.  It's hard to understand what you expect the query result to be.

Comment: That's one of the basic purposes of `group by`: reduce duplicate values to a single one. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you just want it to be ordered by score then

```sql
SELECT user, score FROM guesses ORDER BY score
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c011/1)**

Comment: Ordered by `score, user` I think - "And I want this (below) in which duplicates are alphabetized."

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution! I'm new to MySQL, so I don't know all the words.

Comment: @user104323 You're certainly welcome. Glad it helped. Please, consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you pretend is to order them, not group. In this case, your query can be the following:

```
SELECT user, score FROM guesses ORDER BY score ASC
```

note `ORDER BY score ASC` means from little score to bigger, like you show them in your desired output.

Comment: What about bigger to smaller? I was just planning to read them backwards in php

Comment: In that case, change `ASC` for `DESC` --> `ORDER BY score DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

group by groups elements by the specified column.

What you want is order by, to simply order all records, duplicates or not.

```
    SELECT user, score FROM guesses order by score asc
```